# Restricting users to a branch on GITHUB

Tags: git, github

We have a situation where we need external contractors to do some work on a project but would like to restrict them to a certain branch on our (private) repository and manage the merging of this branch into the release branches ourselves.
Is there a way of restricting users to a single branch of a repository?

Comment: Very much possible with a private repo using gitolite. Gitolite exactly offers this. But I'm not sure about this on github. Did you try contacting the github support people?

Comment: not possible with github in its current state - however it is indeed possible with gitolite like @positron said. if you're going to need that on a regular basis, you could also look at a local installation of gitlab - gitlabhq.com (runs well on a small 512MB RAM VPS, even though it's in RoR)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask that person to fork the project and submit pull request when merging.

Note that their fork will be private, even if their github account is on a free plan.

Comment: I need to do the same thing, having an intern work on a single branch of our private repo. I made a test account to try and request a fork of our private repo, but I don't see how to do this. Any pointers?

Comment: @Kevin_TA: You may want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629538/if-i-fork-someone-elses-private-github-repo-into-my-account-is-it-going-to-app