# GitHub -- Possible to allow certain users to fork my private repo and then submit PR?

Tags: github

I don't want make my repo public.

I only want some certain users to be able to fork this repo and submit PRs. However, I don't want to add them as repo  collaborators who have push privileges.

Is it possible with GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might still consider adding them as collaborator, because you can protect your repo main branch: see "[About protected branches](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/)".

That way: they can clone ([or fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12238769/6309)) your repo, and can push back, but they won't be able to push to `master` (for instance) is `master` is protected: they will have to make a PR.