# ssh clone not cloning repo in git

Tags: git, github, ssh, cygwin, git-clone

I want to clone a repo of another person using ssh. For this I did following things:

- Generated an ssh key in local machine.
- Added the key to the user's account from which the repo has to be cloned.
- Tested whether the key was added by running `ssh -T git@github.com` which outputs : 
  `Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`
- Ran `git clone git@github.com:repo/repo.git`.

The last step outputs Cloning into 'Foldername'... and I can see that the folder is created but no files are present in the folder. I left it for 1 hour but nothing was copied and I also checked the net but its working fine.
I am using cygwin on windows to clone the repo.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you generate your ssh key? Did you add your public key to ***your account***? Have you tried cloning any small public repos?

Comment: Yes I was cloning small repos in the morning with username and password which worked fine, but when I used ssh for cloning with git@github.com:repo/repo.git it just keeps giving cloning foldername.. . I have only added the public key to the remote users's account and is there a need to add the key to my account?

Comment: Who is this "remote user" you keep talking about? Are you trying to clone one of your own repos?

Comment: sorry for the misleading term, actually the repo is not in my account but in my colleague's account. I can't fork it in my account as then it will be public. So I added the key into that account not mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The problem was occurring because of *different home directories of Git bash and cygwin*.

When I generated the ssh key in my cygwin terminal the key was added to *cygwin's .ssh folder* which was `C:\cygwin\home\windows\.ssh` and when I ran the command `ssh -T git@github.com` it authenticated me using the ssh key which was in cygwin's .ssh directory.

But when I ran the command `git clone git@github.com:repo/repo.git`, the key in *git bash's home directory* was used which was in `C:\Users\windows\.ssh`. I copied the key present in cygwin's .ssh folder into this folder and everything worked fine.

However the weird thing is the `git clone git@github.com:repo/repo.git` command didn't threw any error but instead just hanged.

Comment: +1. Good addition to my initial answer which was about the "private" nature of the fork.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't fork it in my account as then it will be public.

Nope: a private repo that you fork... would remain private!
This is detailed in "[If I fork someone else's private Github repo into my account, is it going to appear in my account as a public repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629558/6309)".

So if cloning from your account works, forking the repo of your colleague could be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub is currently experiencing downtime](https://twitter.com/githubstatus/status/364651257568296961) (see also https://status.github.com/), so that might be your issue:

> We're investigating an increase in unicorns.

That's a humorous way to say that people are getting 404s on the pages on GitHub, because their 404 page has a unicorn on it:

[image]

[It's not uncommon for GitHub to experience minor/major outages](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2013/06/02/github-suffers-major-service-outage-taking-website-offline-api-also-affected/), probably because it's such a popular service. They also experience the [occasional DDoS attack](https://twitter.com/githubstatus/status/361865103294992384):

> We're currently experiencing a large DDoS attack. The site is experiencing major ... See more at https://status.github.com/.

Comment: I am trying this for 2 days and was unable to clone it.