# Git: One project with two remote repo maintaining separate commits

Tags: git, github, git-branch

My Client has a github private repo which is shared to me.
I also want to setup a private repo with my developers for the same project.

The issue is that I do not want to push commits of my developers directly to the client repo, but want a separate commit history with my client and developer.

I read about branching but branching will make the new/developer branch visible to my Client.

Is there a way I can Get this form a single directory or I will heave to use two separate project directories, synced with the respective repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fork the private GitHub client repo: it would [still be a private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629558/6309) (even if you don't have a paying account)

Then your developers could push to that fork.

Comment: This means I will have to maintain a two local project directories and sync them manually when required to push the changes to client?

Comment: @Nik no, you can push directly from your local clone of your fork to the original upstream repo. Normally, you would do a PR (Pull Request), but since you have direct access to the original repo, you can push from *one* local clone.

Comment: And Developer commits will not be visible to my Client

Comment: @Nik no, they won't be visible (they won't be "collaborator" of the original repo)... except for their username/email associated to the commits that you will be pushing.