# Access control of GitHub Private Repositories

Tags: git, android-studio, github, bitbucket, pull-request

I am new to GitHub private repositories. I am use to public repositories in GitHub. I know, there is a concept of pull request/ merge pull request.

I am wondering if GitHub PRIVATE repositories have these concepts of pull requests and so!

Actually I am a regular user of BitBucket private repositories. There, I can give read/write/admin access to my team members, and they can directly push/update their work to the repositories with no problem. It is much easier (I feel) than the GitHub Pull request concept.

I assume that the pull request concept is only for the public repositories as a private repository can be controlled (push/pull/update) closely with my team members.

Anyone kindly elaborate with a proper example, how to handle GitHub private repositories for giving access (read/write) to my team.

Note: I am regularly using Android Studio for git integration.
PS: I know how to create private repository and how to work with public repositories by using Pull Request concept.

Comment: I believe that both Bitbucket and GitHub support pull requests even for private repositories.  The only difference being that a private repo's pull requests are only visible to a limited group of people.  If they did not support this, the services would be much less useful.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that the pull request concept is only for the public repositories as a private repository can be controlled (push/pull/update) closely with my team members.

It is for both, since you can:

- make pull request from different branches of the same repo (public/private)
- make pull requests from forks ([a fork of a private repo is private too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629558/6309))

You can:

- [add collaborators to a personal repo](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/).
- or define an [organization and add outside collaborators](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-outside-collaborators-to-repositories-in-your-organization/)